# How to select text on click on text in html?

Tags: javascript, html, select, copy-paste

[image]
I want when clicked on colours to select them and copy them.
They are defined in html like this:

```html
<span>Colour<span>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML and try to explain  `"I want when clicked on colours to select them and copy them"` ~ which colours? where? Are they from `input` elements as suggested by the above image?

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly clear from your question what you want to do. From what I understand you need to change color by entering the hex value which can be done simply by DOM manipulations. Below is a basic code that changes color on button clicking.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];
    var colorIndex = 0;
    function changeColor() {
        var col = document.getElementById("body");
        if( colorIndex >= colors.length ) {
            colorIndex = 0;
        }
        col.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
        colorIndex++;
    }
</script>
    <body id='body'>
    <button onclick="changeColor();">Change color</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Similarly, you can just use the hex code entered in the input box and set the background/line color accordingly. You will need the help of both js and HTML, and also use if or classes as per your need.